# java : stop safety a thread; not using while and boolean flag

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I have a thread that does it's task just one time. I want to stop it if it was not able to do that in an appropriate time. How can I do that? All the methods I have seen before used a while loop and a flag for a task that is done several times; but my task is not like that.

thank you all.

Answer (score 9):

The only clean way of stopping a task is to interrupt it (or set some other flag) which causes the thread to gracefully stop.  If you don't have an outer loop in your code you can check it at various key points where it is safe to interrupt the work flow. This can be tedious for a large code base, but it is the best approach.

If you have a library you have no control over you can use Thread.stop() however this can leave your application in an undefined state. It doesn't kill the thread as such but triggers a ThreadDeath error which will unwind the stack and call finally block etc.  The problem is it will occur in an effectively random line of code (even half way through a line of code) 
A thread can ignore the ThreadDeath error depending on how the code is written.

The only way around this is to run you untrusted code in another process, and then kill that process when it has taken too long.  This could leave temporary files but is a much safer option.

Comment: hi, how the ThreadDeath work? Is it possible to catch it ? If we can't catch it what does it mean "It doesn't kill the thread as such but triggers a ThreadDeath error which will unwind the stack and call finally block etc."

Comment: `ThreadDeath` extends Error and it can be caught (and possibly ignored) like any other Error or Throwable.

Comment: Erm.. You have idea how to catch? I see the Java doc thread.stop() does not thrown this exception.

Comment: You must be reading a different Javadoc to me because that's exactly what it says and even warns about the dangers of catching it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop%28%29

Comment: o.. My mistake, I saw only SecurityException (in the 'thrown' area), so I thought it is not from thread.stop(), I just realize it is unchecked exception.

Comment: The compiler can only check for "throws" exceptions/error thrown in the current thread.  Throwing an exception/error in *another thread* cannot be checked for.

Comment: So am I able to do something like: try { thread.stop()} catch (Exception e){} like this?

Comment: Something like that but different in two respects, a) you need to catch in the thread where it is being thrown not the one triggering it, b) you need to catch an `Error` or `ThreadDeath` or `Throwable` not Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.util.TimerTask` class - It is used to scheduled a task for one-time or repeated execution by a Timer.

Comment: First thank you. But: Timer task has a cancel method that is used to cancel it's execution, if the task is running when this call occurs, the task will run to completion, but will never run again. I want the task to be stopped just I stopped it; I don't want the task to be complete after a period of time it couldn't.

Comment: This works it the task is scheduled and hasn't started but will not once it did.